# How can I connect Atlas MongoDB with a cluster?

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql

I am trying to connect my code to atlas MongoDB but I get the error below, this is my code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://username:test@cluster0.yntdf.mongodb.net/test? 
retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = client["test"]
collection = db["test"]


collection.insert_one({"_id":0, "name": "hello", "score": 5})
```

I got the error:

> ConfigurationError: A DNS label is empty.

How should I handle this error? I installed dnspython and PyMongo.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string is wrong. Double check it is correct and also the IP of the calling server is whitelisted.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue, the following code works for me with python 3.9.1

```
import pymongo
import urllib 
MONGODB_USERNAME = urllib.parse.quote_plus('test')
MONGODB_PASSWORD = urllib.parse.quote_plus('tset@000')
MONGODB_DATABASE = 'sampledb'
MONGODB_URL = "mongodb://"+MONGODB_USERNAME+":"+MONGODB_PASSWORD+"@cluster0.wq5js.mongodb.net/"+MONGODB_DATABASE+"?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
client = pymongo.MongoClient(MONGODB_URL)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following python code works for Mongodb Atlas. Tested with python 3.8 and 3.9.

Reference: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/troubleshoot-connection/#connection-string-issues

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

USERNAME = quote_plus('test')
PASSWORD = quote_plus('test@12345')
DATABASE = 'sampledb'
URI = "mongodb+srv://" + USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD + "@" + DATABASE_HOST

client = MongoClient(URI)
conn = client[DATABASE]
conn.command('ping')
```

Please note that, the user management is not supported by Mongodb Atlas. List of unsupported commands are mentioned [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/unsupported-commands/).